# Click link not working in Robot Framework

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework, ui-automation

```
Open Browser  http://www.netflix.com  safari
Maximize Browser Window
Sleep  2s
#Click Button  xpath=//*[@id="cookie-disclosure"]/div/button
Click Link  link:Sign In
#Click Link  Account
#Click Element  xpath=//*[@id="appMountPoint"]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/a
#Sleep  4s
Wait Until Page Contains  New to Netflix?
Close Browser
```

When I ran the above script I did not get any errors in MAC, but the page is not traversing from home page to sign-in page.

I tried both `xpath` & `link`. I didn't get any errors, in either case, but it's not going to the sign-in page.

Comment: When you say "MAC" are your referring to "Macintosh"? If so, it's "Mac", not "MAC". It's not an acronym, it's an abbreviation. "MAC" usually refers to something else in technical discussions.

Comment: Yes its a spelling mistake. Its Mac.